# Can't write to text file in python with for loop

Tags: python-3.x

This is the entire file.

```
import random
from tkinter.constants import CENTER
import dictionary
import PySimpleGUI as sg




letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

layout = [[sg.Spin(values=[x for x in range(1, 100)], initial_value=1, key='num')],
[sg.Button('Generate', key='Gen')],
[sg.Text(text='', size=(10, 1), justification=CENTER, key='textbox', enable_events=True)],
[sg.Text(text='Words will appear here', key='words', size=(50, 20))]]
window = sg.Window('Random Word Generator', layout, size=(400, 300))
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Gen' and int(values['num'] < 100):
        numWords = int(values['num'])
        letterString = ''
        words = []
        for i in range(100000):
            ran = random.randint(0, 25)
            letterString += letters[ran]
        print(letterString)
        randomletterfile = open('C:.../randomwords.txt', 'w')
        print('Searching.....')
        displayedWords = []
        for word in dictionary.dict:
            if word in letterString and len(word) > 3:
                randomletterfile.write(word)
                words.append(word)
                print(word, end=', ')
        for word in range(numWords):
            displayedWords.append(words[random.randint(0, len(words))])
        print('\nNumber of random words generated: {}'.format(len(words)))
        window['words'].update(displayedWords)
```

The place I am having a problem is here. The text file just comes up blank, sorry if this has been asked before or I'm missing something obvious but I couldn't seem to find an answer anywhere. The file path is correct on my file and it writes a new file every time I run the code.

```
randomletterfile = open('C:.../randomwords.txt', 'w')
        print('Searching.....')
        displayedWords = []
        for word in dictionary.dict:
            if word in letterString and len(word) > 3:
                randomletterfile.write(word)
                words.append(word)
                print(word, end=', ')
```

Comment: I assume that there is data to write to the file (that is, the condition inside the for loop is satisfied). In that case you should either use randomletterfile.close() or randomletterfile.flush() to make sure the data is written to disk. Better yet use context manager (a "with" block).

Comment: @NirH. Used the with statement and it worked! Thank you.